# Oracle Database Script to Delete Users of Certain Role

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am trying to write a script for my Oracle 12C database which would allow me to DROP all users of a certain role but can't seem to get it right.

```
declare
    cursor ID_CURSOR is 
        SELECT USERNAME
            from all_users;
        WHERE granted_role = 'STUDENT'
begin
    for REC in ID_CURSOR loop
        'DROP USER REC CASCADE';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Well your subject line and your example cursor do not match to start.  Nor can you issue DDL from PL/SQL.  You would have to use execute immediate.  See PL/SQL manual.
- -
So to find users granted a specific role you can use

```
select grantee from dba_role_privs where granted_role='ROLE_NAME'
```

and in cursor you use something like

```
 execute immediate 'drop user '||rec.username||' cascade;';
```

however why use PL/SQL to do this?  If this is a one-time effort then just use SQL to generate the drop statements, spool the result, edit to set SQLPlus settings like "set echo on" then run the generated script?
- - Mark D Powell --

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Mark's answer - the simplest way is just to run this script, copy & paste the output, then run that.

```
select 'drop user ' || grantee || ' cascade;' as script
from dba_role_privs 
where granted_role = 'STUDENT';
```

If you really want to use PL/SQL, though, you'd have to do it like this. I used an implicit cursor loop because it's easy and shorter to type.

```
begin
    for REC in (select grantee from dba_role_privs where granted_role = 'STUDENT')
    loop
        execute immediate 'drop user ' || REC.grantee || ' cascade';
    end loop;
end;
/
```